# Unable to install party package ( R) in ADLA

Tags: r, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am trying to install 'party' package in ADLA.

We have tried:

- https://github.com/ArpitSisodia/ADLAwithR-GettingStarted/blob/master/Tutorial/Exercise3/outex3b.txt
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-r-extensions

and few more ways, but party package is not getting installed.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do it, its download the file on datalake in directory:
usqlext\assembly\R\MRS.9.1.0.zip

Them you unzip the file (on a machine without R installed) and execute R.exe on bin folder.

Now you can install all packages you want (with parameter dependencies = true)

```
install.packages('yourpackage', dependencies = TRUE)
```

Zip the folder again and replace the file on datalake by this you created.

Execute RegisterAllAssemblies.USQL again, and your package will be available for you!

```
library('yourpackage')
```

If get not find package error, you need this trick:

```
libpath = .libPaths()[1]
install.packages('yourpackage', lib = libpath)
```